# How to declare and instantiate a new Generic array?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, data-structures, generic-programming

I'm brushing up on my data structure skills. I found a great free book online called [Open Data Structures in Java.](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java-screen.pdf) After reading through it, I'm trying to create all the stated data structures with the code provided so I can instill them in to my memory.

I ran in to an "error" and for the life of me I can't figure it out: in the `resize()` method for the `ArrayStack` (section 2.1.2), there is the line of code - `T[] b = newArray(Math.max(n*2,1));`. The point of this is so the array, which contains the elements, is neither too small or too large. If I use this line of code I get the following error message from Eclipse:

`The method newArray(int) is undefined for the type ArrayStack<T>.`

So, I'm thinking that it must have been a "typo" and what was meant was "new Array". But fixing that leaves me with the following error message from Eclipse:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Array to T[]`.

I don't understand what I'm missing or doing wrong. **So to sum up my question,** how do you declare and instantiate a new generic array, particularly at a fixed size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not make this a simple matter.  Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) the class of T is not available at runtime (which is when you need to determine what type of array to create).

However, since you already have an array (`a`), you can use reflection to create a new array of that type.

It will look something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Test {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                Object array[] = new Object[5];

                array = resizeArray(array, 10);

                for (Object o : array) {
                        System.out.println(o);
                }
        }

        public static <T>
        T[] resizeArray(T[] a, int newSize) throws Exception {
                T[] b = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(),
                                                newSize);

                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                        b[i] = a[i];
                }

                return b;
        }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the line `T[] b = newArray(Math.max(n*2,1));` in the book was merely making the reference that I would have to create a new array? It's not code to do so in itself? So I'll probably have to use `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance()` to create an array of arbitrary type.

Comment: @AndroidStudent, I think so.  I just added example code to my answer.  I can see how the book's author wouldn't want to put that monstrosity in his code as it would distract from the topic at hand.

Comment: To be fair, the author of said book should've pointed out his code is invalid, or just used `Object[]`. Seems a little sloppy.

Comment: Maybe they should have used a language with better support for parameterized types....

Comment: @AndroidStudent It appears that `newArray()` is a method call. I cannot find where it is defined in the text you linked, though.

Answer (score 2):

Given the class of `T`, let's call it `klass`...

For a one-dimensional array of length `n`:

```
T[] arr = (T[]) Array.newInstance(klass, n)
```

For a two-dimensional array of length `n x m`:

```
T[][] 2dArr = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(klass, n, m)
```

The above are actually two different functions, one takes an `int` argument and the second takes an `int...` argument, which you can also pass as an array. Both return an `Object` for which you need an unchecked cast.

If you want a jagged array of length `n`, second dimension undetermined, you will have to get the class of `T[]`, let's call it `klass2`, and then do

```
T[][] 2dArr2 = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(klass2, n)
```

This is why you also need to pass in a type to `collection.toArray(T[] arr)`, otherwise you get an `Object[]` for the vanilla `toArray()` method because it doesn't know the type.

Answer (score 1):

What you would like is:

```
void resize() {
    T[] b = new T[Math.max(n*2,1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    a = b;
}
```

But that does not work because T is not actually known at runtime, and it would have to be.  However this can be written with a generic-safe constructor.

```
void resize() {
    T[] b = (T[]) Array.newInstance( a.getClass().getComponentType(),
                                     Math.max(n*2,1) );
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    a = b;
}
```

It appears that the author meant to have a method, newArray in that class:

```
void T[] newArray(int size) {
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance( a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't let you do that for Generics, it gives you this error message: `Cannot create a generic array of T`.

Comment: OK, I see now.  You have your answer from Samuel Edwin Ward that gets around the type erasure problem.